# Lazy Loading of data in a Listview with only one URL+android

Tags: android

I have a URL which loads about 500 records of data which is taking lot of time to download and display in Listview. I would like use lazy loading to display the data but since when i call the asynchronous task the url gets called and it fetches all the data.but i would like to display first few record and then when scrolled should load the next records.please kindly let me know the logic to acheive this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you have access to the webservice you are calling to get the data? It sounds to me like you need to change the webservice so that it only returns a limited number of records at a time.

Comment: @Dave yes i have access to web service that i m calling..i will make the webservice to return limited records and let u know the result..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

there is alooot of solutions to resolve this problem.

**I have for my self a couple of them:**
1) [LazyList](https://github.com/thest1/LazyList) this is a good example
2) I use [AQuery](http://code.google.com/p/android-query/) to resolve the lazy and asynchronous issues.

Comment: @IamStalker how can i make my url to fetch few records and set them to listview and fetch the remaining in background?

Comment: @hemanth kumar it's simple, you need to create a RESTful api in server side that makes a possibility to call for certain amount of items, after that you just have to load them in background using Background Worker thread.

Comment: No problem, do you need any code solutions? Or you will try to resolve it on your own?

Answer (score 0):

I thing first create custome listview and when you set data on listview that time this process write in thread.i thing easy way